# Makefile removes argument post white space value when called from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I've written a small bash script to invoke a `make` command.
The makefile expects `args='<arguments to be passed to program>'` argument. (i.e. `make a args='--aaa 5 --bbb 6'`)
The problem is when I use the script to invoke the make command, the argument is truncated on its first white space.
For example, when executing `make a args='--aaa 5'` through the script, the `args` variable is `'--aaa` and not `'--aaa 5'`
I've also tried adding quotes and single quotes but the result is the same.
When I invoke the `make` command manually through terminal the, the `args` variable gets all the arguments and their values as expected.

Here is the script call :

```
args="args='--aaa 5 --bbb 6'"
make a ${args}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us how you're calling it from your script?

Comment: @larsks edited.. thanks

Comment: Why not `args=( --aaa 5 --bbb 6 ); make a "${args[@]}"` ?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Presumably, the Makefile calls a program that expects an argument like this.

Comment: @chepner Seems odd :-) But OK.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein , chepner is right :)

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein An example would be something like `CFLAGS='-g -O2'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to double-quote `$args` to preserve the whitespace.

```
make a "$args"
```

I'm assuming the Makefile correctly handles the value once it receives it.

Comment: That worked... Thanks ! (Weird part is when I tried putting the whole command in quotation marks and it didn't work)